# MySQL, group last months data by day?

Tags: mysql

I'm interested in knowing how many users signed up each day of last month. I have this very simple query that tells me how many users signed up last month. How do I modify the query to give me results by day?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, created_at
FROM users
WHERE created_at > '2017-01-01'
AND created_at < '2017-02-01'
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Check out group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) as user_cnt, created_at
FROM users
WHERE created_at > '2017-01-01'
AND created_at < '2017-02-01'
GROUP  BY created_at
```

If `created_at`  field is datetime

```
SELECT count(*) as user_cnt, date(created_at) as created_date
FROM users
WHERE created_at > '2017-01-01'
AND created_at < '2017-02-01'
GROUP  BY date(created_at)
```

Comment: nevermind it's working, just a little differently then I expected :) thansk